# vb.net Filling data-set value as combo-box value-member issue

Tags: sql, vb.net, oracle, combobox

```
        myORAConnection.Open()

        Dim SQLString As String = "Select child_id as id, child_name as name from xxi_org_structure_v Where parent_id=" & LegalEntity & ""
        Dim cmd As New OracleCommand(SQLString, myORAConnection, OraTrans)
        Dim daTableORA As New OracleDataAdapter(cmd)
        daTableORA.Fill(dtOrg)

        daTableORA.Dispose()
        cmd.Dispose()
        myORAConnection.Close()

        With IT_ORG_CODEComboBox
            .DataSource = dtOrg.Tables(0)
            .ValueMember = "id"
            .DisplayMember = "name"
        End With

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try

    'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'Main_POSDataSet.pos_promotion_item_group_details' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
    Me.Pos_promotion_item_group_detailsTableAdapter.Fill(Me.Main_POSDataSet.pos_promotion_item_group_details)

    'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'Main_POSDataSet.pos_promotion_item_group_headers' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
    Me.Pos_promotion_item_group_headersTableAdapter.Fill(Me.Main_POSDataSet.pos_promotion_item_group_headers)
```

I am filling the combobox with value from oracle, but getting the selected value from sql and storing it to sql too.

I am getting the value to fill in the form from "Main_POSDataSet.pos_promotion_item_group_headers", however I want to tell the form or the dataset or the combobox that the value retrieved from the "IT_ORG_CODE" column is to be used as combobox value-member and not display member.

is there anyway to solve this please ?

[image]

237 is the organisation id to use as combobox valuemember, but here it is used as display member !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replace

```
Me.IT_ORG_CODEComboBox.DataBindings.Add(New System.Windows.Forms.Binding("Text", Me.Pos_promotion_item_group_headersBindingSource, "IT_ORG_CODE", True))
```

With

```
Me.IT_ORG_CODEComboBox.DataBindings.Add(New System.Windows.Forms.Binding("SelectedValue", Me.Pos_promotion_item_group_headersBindingSource, "IT_ORG_CODE", True))
```

in the form designer code